# Inline CSS to Angular 2 - linear-gradient to background image

Tags: html, angular, css

I have the usual `css` style like:

```
.main-body {
    height: stretch;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url('../assets/img/background.png');
}
```

In the above, I need to move

`background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url('../assets/img/background.png');`

to inline styling. I'm trying to do it as below:

UPDATE:

```
<div class="container-fluid main-body" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url(backgroundUrl)'}">>
</div>
```

However, this is not working. It's picking up the right styling, however, it can't locate the `backgroundUrl` which is defined in the component.

ANSWER:

Okay, found the error. Just needed to use it as below:

```
<div class="container-fluid main-body" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url('+backgroundUrl+')'}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with the url being added. Angular has a weird thing with inlining background images that requires forward slashes and backslashes. In my own project, I added:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url(\'assets/images/generic-car.jpg\')'}"
```

and it did show up inlined. I attached a screenshot of it.

[image]

Comment: This came quite close, however, the url is still not getting recognised. I'm trying to pass it as a variable, but still not working. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you missed some "'"

```
<div class="container-fluid main-body" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url(\'../assets/img/background.png\')}'">
```

I am not sure about this(escape) -> ...\'../assets/img/background.png\'...

You can try moving it to variable like,

```
 <some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>
```

---